# Make error when compiling GMP on Windows

Tags: windows, mingw, gmp

I'm attempting to compile GMP 5.1.3 with MinGW on a 64 bit Windows 7 machine as a prerequisite to setting up pycrypto. To configure GMP I used `./configure --prefix=C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/gmp-5.1.3`. When I enter the `make` command, I get the error:

```
../libtool: line 1109: lib: command not found
make[2]: *** [libmpn.la] Error 127
make[2]: Leaving director '/c/Python27/Lib/site-packages/gmp-5.1.3/mpn'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/c/Python27/Lib/site-packages/gmp-5.1.3'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I've been fishing around Google and reviewing the instructions for GMP to no avail. Found lots of maybe similar problems, but nothing that directly relates. Though I have the sneaking suspicion that the problem is right in front of me and I've just been staring at the screen too long.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ykb2k5f.aspx doesn't seem to be installed, or in your PATH.

Comment: Good call. I added /VC/bin to PATH and it fixed it.